# Downstream job configuration not visible, still triggers downstream builds

Tags: jenkins

How are the downstream jobs configured in this maven project, I do not see any configuration to trigger the jobs, then how is it being triggered. Any idea?

Is there any other way a downstream job can be configured apart from the job configuration.

Job configuration:

```
<maven2-moduleset plugin="maven-plugin@2.12.1">
<actions/>
<description/>
<logRotator class="hudson.tasks.LogRotator">
    <daysToKeep>-1</daysToKeep>
    <numToKeep>-1</numToKeep>
    <artifactDaysToKeep>30</artifactDaysToKeep>
    <artifactNumToKeep>25</artifactNumToKeep>
</logRotator>
<keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
<properties>
    <hudson.plugins.disk__usage.DiskUsageProperty plugin="disk-usage@0.28"/>
</properties>
<scm class="hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM" plugin="git@2.4.0">
    <configVersion>2</configVersion>
    <userRemoteConfigs>
        <hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
        <url>
            http://scm-url/scm/git/git-repo.git
        </url>
    </hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
    </userRemoteConfigs>
    <branches>
        <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
        <name>origin/develop</name>
        </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
    </branches>
    <doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>false</doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>
    <submoduleCfg class="list"/>
    <extensions/>
</scm>
<canRoam>true</canRoam>
<disabled>true</disabled>
<blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
<blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
<triggers/>
<concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
<rootModule>
    <groupId>au.com.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
</rootModule>
<goals>
    clean install -Pdev4.publish1,autoInstallPackage -X
</goals>
<aggregatorStyleBuild>true</aggregatorStyleBuild>
<incrementalBuild>false</incrementalBuild>
<ignoreUpstremChanges>true</ignoreUpstremChanges>
<archivingDisabled>false</archivingDisabled>
<siteArchivingDisabled>false</siteArchivingDisabled>
<fingerprintingDisabled>false</fingerprintingDisabled>
<resolveDependencies>false</resolveDependencies>
<processPlugins>false</processPlugins>
<mavenValidationLevel>-1</mavenValidationLevel>
<runHeadless>false</runHeadless>
<disableTriggerDownstreamProjects>false</disableTriggerDownstreamProjects>
<blockTriggerWhenBuilding>true</blockTriggerWhenBuilding>
<settings class="jenkins.mvn.DefaultSettingsProvider"/>
<globalSettings class="jenkins.mvn.DefaultGlobalSettingsProvider"/>
<reporters/>
<publishers>
    <hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver>
        <artifacts>**/*.zip</artifacts>
        <allowEmptyArchive>false</allowEmptyArchive>
        <onlyIfSuccessful>false</onlyIfSuccessful>
        <fingerprint>false</fingerprint>
        <defaultExcludes>true</defaultExcludes>
    </hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver>
</publishers>
<buildWrappers>
    <hudson.plugins.ansicolor.AnsiColorBuildWrapper plugin="ansicolor@0.4.1">
        <colorMapName>xterm</colorMapName>
    </hudson.plugins.ansicolor.AnsiColorBuildWrapper>
</buildWrappers>
<prebuilders/>
<postbuilders/>
<runPostStepsIfResult>
    <name>SUCCESS</name>
    <ordinal>0</ordinal>
    <color>BLUE</color>
    <completeBuild>true</completeBuild>
</runPostStepsIfResult>
```

Answer (score 1):

The configuration is stored the other way around. It's the downstream job that keeps track of its upstream job(s):

```
<project>
  <!-- ... -->
  <triggers>
    <jenkins.triggers.ReverseBuildTrigger>
      <spec/>
      <upstreamProjects>my-upstream-project</upstreamProjects>
      <threshold>
        <name>SUCCESS</name>
        <ordinal>0</ordinal>
        <color>BLUE</color>
        <completeBuild>true</completeBuild>
      </threshold>
    </jenkins.triggers.ReverseBuildTrigger>
  </triggers>
  <!-- ... -->
</project>
```